# How to reset name shown in terminal 

Tags: command-line

When I installed ubuntu 12, my terminal was showing user@XYZ. After fiddling with some external application, now my terminal looks like this user@ABC. How to switch back to XYZ?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATED:

I changed my `/etc/hosts` file from

```
127.0.0.1   localhost


127.0.1.1   MyUbuntu
```

To

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.1.1   ubun12 server.ubun12 dev.ubun12 *.ubun12
```

So previously it was `admin@MyUbuntu`, but now it is `admin@ubun12`

Answer (score 5):

Are XYZ and ABC what it actually show(ed)? Because if thats the case it sounds like you've changed your machine name. You can change the terminal prompt with

```
export PS1="(Prompt)"
```

so I imagine you'd want something like

```
export PS1=`whoami`@`hostname`:
```

to show

```
bob@bobs-computer:
```

but to change your hostname you'd need

```
sudo hostname (new name)
```

Comment: I think, I need to apply different IP like 127.0.1.2, to get back to original state

Comment: @Minty, No just change the line that starts with 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts to `127.0.1.1 MyUbuntu ubun12 server.ubunt12 dev.ubun12` I don't think you really want the *.ubunt12 entry.  You may also need to run `sudo hostname MyUbuntu`.  You may also need to restart, or at least logoff/logon. This answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but something really screwed up in the past 30 min. Things just stopped working. I am closing this issue because I am starting all over again and I will keep your suggestion to include that next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As jackweirdy mentioned above, what you want is just get your hostname "XYZ" back, right?

just feel free to type the commands as follows,

```
echo "XYZ" > /etc/hostname
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Hope it helps, more for PS1 configuration, visit [PS1 Configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) to customize your own prompt :D

Oh, one more thing if you want to configure your domain name as well, edit /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1        localhost.localdomain    localhost
12.34.56.78      XYZ.example.com        XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am starting all over again because things went wrong and I dont know where to look. But I will keep your suggestion.